# vertex weighting and 3ds max

Tags: 3dsmax, 3ds

Does anyone know if the .3ds file has vertex weight info for skeletal animations? If so what's the chunk name to access this info.  I was almost sure it did have this info but can't seem to figure how to get it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skin weights are not a part of the base spec. But 3ds does support custom blocks of data so it could be extended to port arrays of weights. But both importer and exporter would have to support this extension.

from ofile.h in 3ds import/export project of 3dsmax sdk

```
/* NOTE Numbers 0x8000 through 0x8FFF are reserved for external
applications to include in APP_DATA chunks */
#define APP_DATA 0x8000
```

There is no mention of weights in the entire source for import and export. This would make sense since the format hasn't been in active use since 1996 when most 3D creation software didn't support skinning out of the box.